# Query in all values of a item using terms in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query searches some stuff on the `source_id` `27` and `64`.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_search?pretty=true' -d'
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
     "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
              "default_field": "body",
              "query": "somestring"
           }
        },
        {
           "terms": {
              "source_id": ["27", "64"]
           }
        },
        {
           "has_child": {
              "type": "user_item_relation",
              "query": {
                 "bool": {
                    "must": [
                       {
                          "term": {
                             "user_id": 12
                          }
                       },
                       {
                          "term": {
                             "favorite": 0
}}]}}}}]}}}'
```

Is there any way **mantaining the json structure (without removing the `terms` field or adding or removing any other field)**, to search in all `source_id` records instead of just specific ones?.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
{
   "terms": {
      "source_id": *
   }
},
```

Comment: What if you remove `terms` clause in above query? Won't that work?

Comment: Due to the implementation of the API, I can't remove `terms`

Comment: I didn't understand. Is t necessary for you to use `term`. If yes can you explain why??

Comment: It's just an example. As I stated on the question, I want to know if there's a way to search in all records instead of the ones that you specify.

Comment: Can you use `query_string` instead of `term` . You can specify regex in `query_string`